# Looping through excel files in a folder, extracting columns, pasting them in a master file with 1 empty column in between

Tags: vba, excel, loops, offset

I recently started working with VBA, and assigned myself a project in order to get the hang of it.

For now, this macro is supposed to loop through a folder for all Excel files. Extract a range from each of them, and paste them next to eachother, with one empty column in between, in a master workbook.

[Master workbook](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1fe9IxprffwSlJtVVAtdFN3a1E)

[Source workbook1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1fe9IxprffwNzFsM19aMHFDTWc)

I wanted to add another source workbook, but my reputation doesn't allow this yet.

The following code is what I came up with the past weeks, however I can imagine it can be a lot cleaner.

For now I am not able to get an empty column in between the pasted columns and for some reason the last extracted column is pasted twice.

Could you help me with these issues?

```
Sub SelectDataTestLoop2()
    'Dim file location and file name etc.
    Dim FilePath As Variant
    Dim FileName As Variant
    Dim WBcount As Integer
    Dim OtherWB As Workbook
    Dim ThisWB As Workbook
    Dim ThisWS As Worksheet
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    'Sheet in which the data needs to be pasted (SignalCompilationFile)
    Set ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ThisWS = ActiveSheet

    'Define file location and file name
    FilePath = "C:\Users\907443\Desktop\VBA Test\FileTestMap\"
    FileName = Dir(FilePath & "*.xls?")

    WScount = 0

    'Loop over all files in a folder, copy/paste data
    While FileName <> ""
        Set OtherWB = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & FileName)

        For Each WS In OtherWB.Worksheets
            Set CopyRange = OtherWB.Worksheets(4).Range("H2:H114")
            Set PasteRange = ThisWS.Cells(21, 14)

            CopyRange.Copy
            PasteRange.Offset(0, WScount).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            WScount = WScount + (1 / 7)
        Next WS

        FileName = Dir()
        Set OtherWB = Nothing
    Wend

    ThisWB.Activate
    ThisWS.Activate
    Set ThisWB = Nothing
    Set ThisWS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Some notes: (1) How does adding `1/7` (which is a floating point number `0.142…`) to an integer counter `WScount = WScount + (1 / 7)` make any sense? What are you trying here? (2) Setting variables to nothing is unnecessary VBA does this automatically on `End Sub`. (3) Don't ever use `Variant` unless you know why you need to. `FilePath` and `FileName` should be `String`.

Comment: You may want to close `OtherWB` when you're done with it... `OtherWB.Close`

Comment: @Peh (1) I failed to add that I need the data from one workbook only added once. Adding 1/7 was my make-shift solution to make the macro paste the column only once, instead of 7 times. The sourcebooks contain 7 worksheets. (2) Those are artifacts of my lack of understanding of VBA (yet). I don't yet see the (ir)relevance of every piece of code yet. (3) Same as part (2), thanks for the info that's why I ask my question here.

Comment: @SkeXyz OK, I still didn't understand that `1/7` thing you tried. But that was definitely not working. But have a look at @Variatus answer which makes this clear already.

Answer (score 1):

I have commented your code and hope it helps.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectDataTestLoop2()
    'Dim file location and file name etc.
    Dim FilePath As String                  'Variant
    Dim FileName As String                  'Variant
    Dim WBcount As Integer
    Dim OtherWB As Workbook
    Dim ThisWB As Workbook
    Dim ThisWS As Worksheet
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Dim CopyRange As Range                  ' declare all variables
    Dim TargetColumn As Long

    'Sheet in which the data needs to be pasted (SignalCompilationFile)
    Set ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook             ' logically, I expect ThisWorkbook
    Set ThisWS = ActiveSheet

    'Define file location and file name
    FilePath = "C:\Users\907443\Desktop\VBA Test\FileTestMap\"
    FileName = Dir(FilePath & "*.xls?")

'    WScount = 0                             ' the Dim statement sets the value = 0
                                            ' but there is no Dim statment for WScount
                                            ' use "Option Explicit" at the top of your code sheet

    TargetColumn = 2                        ' define the frist column to paste to (2 = "B")
    'Loop over all files in a folder, copy/paste data
    While FileName <> ""
        Set OtherWB = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & FileName)

        For Each WS In OtherWB.Worksheets
            Set CopyRange = OtherWB.Worksheets(4).Range("H2:H114")
'            Set PasteRange = ThisWS.Cells(21, 14)      ' this specifies N21

            CopyRange.Copy
'            PasteRange.Offset(0, WScount).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            ' paste to row 2 in Targetcolumn
            ThisWS.Cells(2, TargetColumn).PasteSpecial
            TargetColumn = TargetColumn + 2

'            WScount = WScount + (1 / 7)
            WBcount = WBcount + 1
        Next WS

        FileName = Dir()
        OtherWB.Close SaveChanges:=False    ' close the workbook after you are done with it
'        Set OtherWB = Nothing
    Wend

'    ThisWB.Activate                        ' after all OtherWb are closed
                                            ' this will be the ActiveWorkbook
'    ThisWS.Activate                        ' - ditto -
''    Set ThisWB = Nothing
''    Set ThisWS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate info and clean-up. I failed to add that data from one workbook only needs to be pasted once, instead of 7 times. I tried to correct for it myself by adding the 'WScount + (1/7)' to it, but that seems rather devious. Also if I try out the code only data from the first workbook in the folder is added. Lastly, I'm wondering why you added this part:    'FilePath = "H:\Name Change Test File\"'?

Comment: The FilePath "H:\..." was for my testing and forgotten. I removed it. The code will loop through all Excel workbooks @ FilePath, opening each one, and then loops through each worksheet, copying from each. There is no telling how many workbooks there might be or how many worksheets in each. Your WBcount, alias WScount, has no purpose apparent in the code segment you posted. In the location where the counter is now it will count all worksheets from all workbooks (the number of copies totally pasted). If you want to count workbooks move the counter below the `Next WS`.